# How to paste SPSS output using the LIST command into SPSS - the output all pastes into one cell

Tags: spss

If I use select if and then list some variables, the output appears as a plain text table in the output viewer.

When I paste this into Excel it all goes into one cell.

I've tried the copy special options and none of them seem to make a difference. Also the columns of data are all separated by different numbers of spaces, which means I can't do a find and replace to switch the spaces for commas or tabs.

How can I get this output so that I can paste it into excel with each variable in its own column?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about statistics.

Comment: This is clearly a technical Excel question. Look for how Excel can split a column of cells into several columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Windows user with a relatively plain solution for problems like this:

1. Paste table into [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29).
2. Find and replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) all pairs of spaces ($\ \ $) with a single space.

   - Repeat as necessary until no two spaces are adjacent.
3. Enter a <kbd>Tab</kbd> somewhere, then select and cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) it.
4. Find and replace all spaces with the tab (   ), which you can paste into the `Replace with:` field, but can't enter there directly with a simple keystroke.
5. Copy the table and paste into Excel, which parses the tabs as column separators by default.

   - You may have to fix some errors manually on occasion (e.g., if empty cells are left blank)...so there may be better ways to do this for [users more "Super"](http://superuser.com) than myself. I'd love to know if so.

Comment: Can you make your dainty buttons clickable? :-)

Comment: What, so you could make them appear to depress into the screen when you click on them? Wouldn't know how, but I'd love to know if there's a way to do that too!